# Bash: How to use a variable as an argument with multiple sets of quotes

Tags: bash, variables, loops, escaping, eyed3

I have a folder full of mp3s and I want to strip out all id3 usertext frames (except replaygain) - this code I wrote will do it, but it will loop through each file, for each found tag, to remove it. This results in the script cycling over each mp3 multiple times to do the task I want.

Here's the code that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
userframes=`eyeD3 *.mp3 | grep UserTextFrame | grep -v replaygain | awk -F ":" '{print $3}' | sed 's/]//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/\s*$//g' | sort | uniq`

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $userframes; do
    eyeD3 --user-text-frame="$f:" *.mp3
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I would like to be more efficient and use each entry in the variable once against each mp3 like this:

```
eyeD3 --user-text-frame="desc1:" --user-text-frame="desc2:" *.mp3
```

But I can't figure out how to do it. I think I got close by trying to craft the list all at once with the switches in a variable, but there are some weird character escape issues I can't figure out.

```
eyeD3 *.mp3 | grep UserTextFrame | grep -v replaygain | awk -F ":" '{print $3}' | sed 's/]//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/\s*$//g' | sort | uniq | sed -e "s|'|"'\\\'"'|g" | awk '{print "--user-text-frame=\x27" $0 ":\x27"}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

which makes a list like this (I've tried double quotes instead of singles, and escaped double quotes):

```
--user-text-frame='ALBUMARTISTSORT:' --user-text-frame='ASIN:' --user-text-frame='Album Artist Credit:' --user-text-frame='Artist Credit:' --user-text-frame='CATALOGNUMBER:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Album Artist Id:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Album Id:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Album Release Country:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Album Status:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Album Type:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Artist Id:' --user-text-frame='MusicBrainz Release Group Id:' --user-text-frame='Script:'
```

but I can't successfully pass that as a variable to eyeD3 like this:

```
frames=`eyeD3 *.mp3 | grep UserTextFrame | grep -v replaygain | awk -F ":" '{print $3}' | sed 's/]//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/\s*$//g' | sort | uniq | sed -e "s|'|"'\\\'"'|g" | awk '{print "--user-text-frame=\x27" $0 ":\x27"}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

eyeD3 $frames *.mp3
```

I either get an error

*"eyeD3: error: unrecognized arguments: Credit:' Album Artist Id:' Album Id:' Album Release Country:' Album Status:' Album Type:' Artist Id:' Release Group Id:' 01 - Do The Joy.mp3 02 - Love.mp3 03 - So Light Is Her Footfall.mp3 04 - Be A Bee.mp3 05 - Missing The Light Of The Day.mp3 06 - Tropical Disease.mp3 07 - Heaven's Light.mp3 08 - Night Hunter.mp3 09 - Sing Sang Sung.mp3 10 - Eat My Beat.mp3 11 - You Can Tell It To Everybody.mp3 12 - African Velvet.mp3"*

Or if I try and play with escaping quotes I'll ending up adding more duplicate tags on top of the existing ones like

```
'tag
tag
```

where it used to be

```
tag
```

Maybe there's an easier way to do what I want?

EDIT:

Syntax of eyeD3 command according to the help:

```
--user-text-frame DESC:TEXT
                    Set the value of a user text frame (i.e., TXXX). To
                    remove the frame, specify an empty value. e.g.,
                    --user-text-frame='SomeDesc:'
```

so as an example:

```
eyeD3 --user-text-frame='ALBUMARTISTSORT:' *.mp3
```

should remove the user-text frame tag with the description ALBUMARTISTSORT from all mp3s in that directory

typical outpout from eyeD3 with one file (typing in *mp3 just produces multiple entries for all mp3s in dir)

```
$ eyeD3 12\ -\ African\ Velvet.mp3 
12 - African Velvet.mp3 [ 6.82 MB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 03:51 MPEG1, Layer III    [ ~247 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.3:
title: African Velvet
artist: Air
album: Love 2
recording date: 2009
track: 12       genre: Electronic (id 52)
disc: 1/1
BPM: 0
Publisher/label: Emi
Unique File ID: [http://musicbrainz.org] : c5981690-b9ef-45f4-a8ce-7696a75190fb
Comment: [Description: ] [Lang: eng]

Lyrics: [Description: ] [Lang: eng]

UserTextFrame: [Description: replaygain_album_gain]
-9.11 dB
UserTextFrame: [Description: replaygain_album_peak]
1.238762
UserTextFrame: [Description: replaygain_track_gain]
-7.69 dB
UserTextFrame: [Description: replaygain_track_peak]
1.026620
UserTextFrame: [Description: CATALOGNUMBER]
509999663960-3
UserTextFrame: [Description: Album Artist Credit]
Air
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Album Type]
album
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Album Artist Id]
cb67438a-7f50-4f2b-a6f1-2bb2729fd538
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Artist Id]
cb67438a-7f50-4f2b-a6f1-2bb2729fd538
UserTextFrame: [Description: Script]
Latn
UserTextFrame: [Description: ASIN]
B002G9TWQQ
UserTextFrame: [Description: Artist Credit]
Air
UserTextFrame: [Description: ALBUMARTISTSORT]
Air
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Release Group Id]
34961bd0-b55b-4e9c-97eb-99763419afc0
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Album Id]
7e445cb0-3df7-3c38-b318-d68713294ff8
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Album Status]
Official
UserTextFrame: [Description: MusicBrainz Album Release Country]
CA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please post the raw output of the `eyeD3` command. Given the presence of white space in the output, you going to have to abandon the approach of storing the entire output in a single variable. Using an array may be feasible, if we can see how to parse it correctly.

Comment: Do you want to know the syntax of the command 
"--user-text-frame DESC:TEXT"? I've added that to the main post above. If you need anything more let me know.

Comment: added eyeD3 output example as well

Answer (score 0):

Please put a pair of double quote around your variable

```
eyeD3 "$frames" *.mp3
```

Comment: eyeD3 doesn't throw an error, but doesn't do anything either. Tags remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
regex='UserTextFrame: [Description: (.*)]'
eyeD3 *.mp3 | grep UserTextFrame | grep -v replaygain | while read; do
    [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done | sort -u | while read frame; do
    eyeD3 --user-text-frame "$frame:" *.mp3 
done
```

The first three stages of the pipeline are the same as yours. Next, I use a simple `while` loop and regular expression match to output the text that follows "Description", up to the closing bracket. The output of this while loop consists of all descriptions, over all the MP3s. This is piped through `sort -u` to eliminate duplicates, then fed into another `while` loop with removes each unique item from all MP3s.

Comment: I don't get any output when I run that and the tags don't change.

The "--user-text-frame DESC:" should be "--user-text-frame=DESC:" to remove the tag, so I added the = in there but the result is the same.

Comment: To get your code to work:
[http://pastebin.com/tMMdGvAz]

Which does the same thing as the for loop I originally posted. It cycles through each mp3 over and over to remove the tags one at a time. I was wanting to remove them all at one time per mp3. This can only be done by adding multiple "--user-text-frame DESC:TEXT" arguements